# Custom tailwind keyframes not working in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Following the [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/animation#using-custom-values), I got to the end of this page that says how to add custom keyframes for use with tailwind classes, but can't get any custom animations to work.

I've done the following:

1. tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
          wiggle: {
            "0%, 100%": { transform: "rotate(-3deg)" },
            "50%": { transform: "rotate(3deg)" },
          },
        },
        animation: {
          wiggle: "wiggle 1s ease-in-out infinite",
        },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

2. _app.tsx:

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState<Notification | null>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="animate-wiggle wiggle">asdf</div>
      {notification && (
        <Notification type={notification.type} message={notification.message} />
      )}
      <Component {...pageProps} setNotification={setNotification} />
    </>
  );
}
```

And it just doesn't want to work. I can't figure out why. The class is applied, but no keyframe animation. The default tailwind animations work fine.

You can find the whole repo here:
https://github.com/ic-768/word-station

Comment: you seem to have a duplicated `keyframes` key inside `keyframes` object

Comment: You're right. must have added it by accident while debugging. The issue stil persists unfotunately.

Comment: Does `_app.tsx` file within `pages` or `components` directories?

Comment: It's inside of pages